# Two loop foreach and unset

Tags: php, foreach

```
<?php

$array = array(a,s,d,f,g,h,j,k,l);

foreach($array as $i => &$a){
 foreach($array as $k => &$b){
    if($k = 4){
     unset($array[1]);
    }
 }

 echo $a . "\n";
}

print_r($array);
```

**CODEPAD:** http://codepad.org/UoWhrIkv

Why in this example `echo` show me only `"a"` and `print_r` show all good? Is possible to make good showing in loop with `echo`?

Comment: What that means, using single equal sign in if statement ?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this? I don't see the reason for the 2nd loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems here:

The first is you're using `=` instead of `==` in this line:

```
if($k = 4){
```

The second is your logic, as when your inner loop iterates over the same array, it will repeatedly unset `$array[1]`.

That does not influence the inner foreach, but the outer one. So `echo $a;` has a chance to print once only.

Changing your `if` statement to:

```
if($k == 4){
  unset( $b);
}
```

Made the `echo $a` [print the entire array](http://codepad.org/k4wyuMr3) (assuming that's what you're going for).

Comment: The unset operation was only done one time. That did *reset* the array pointer in `$array` bringing both `foreach` operations to an end. Using `unset($b)` *does not* reset the array pointer in `$array`, it removes only a reference (actually does nothing, you can also suggest to remove the inner `foreach` completely). Just for additional explanation. Or better say: The second half of your answer is completely wrong (sorry no offence, took me a while as well to figure that out).

Comment: Makes sense - I didn't look into it too deeply, just tried a few things that came to mind and saw that one "worked".

Comment: Looks that I'm wrong, too. the unset operation does what you said, and it's more than once. I tested it but now testing reveals this. Urgh. My first test was with the corrected `if ($k == 4)`, that's why it only executed once. But this still resets the outer loop, so partly we both were right ^^

Comment: Yes, absolutely. That's why I'm asking myself - apart from the problem we think about - what made that guy write such code in the first place. Also what does "make good showing in loop" actually mean? `echo "good\n";`?

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if your trying to have strings in the array or constants, but strings should be formatted like this.

```
$array = array('a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l');
```

Another thing you have wrong is your if statement

```
if($k == 4)
```

You need to use the double equal sign to compare, a single = sign is used for assignment.

Could you also provide exactly what you are trying to do here, because your code has some formatting issues off the bat, which could be why a was the only one printing.

Answer (score 3):

> Why in this example `echo` show me only `"a"` and `print_r` show all good?

When you modify an array you are iterating over in [`foreach`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/foreach) (here you remove an element), the behaviour of `foreach` might give you unexpected things. The note from the manual page says:

> As foreach relies on the internal array pointer changing it within the loop may lead to unexpected behavior.

---

> Is possible to make good showing in loop with echo?

Yes, but it depends on what you try to achieve. As you have not specified what "good showing" actually means, we can only guess:

- Assign `$array` to a new variable, and use that variable within the `foreach`s.
- -OR- Don't use the references `&$a` and `&$b`, just use `$a` and `$b`.
- -OR- Save which elements to delete and skip those within the iteration.
- -OR- ...
- -OR- even `echo "good\m";`?

A working code-example could look like this ([Demo](http://codepad.org/PiEyC3aj)):

```
$array = array('a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l');

foreach ($array as $i => &$a) {
    echo "$a\n";
}

print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using [references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) (`&$a` and `&$b`)